# PHP restrict user to directory by session uid/pwd

Tags: php, session-scope

I have my user mgmt system setup, but how do I re-direct and restrict a user to her/his folder/sub-folders/files according to the `$_SESSION['uid']; $_SESSION['pwd'];` established when s/he logs in?

I'm using a MySQL-based user mgmt setup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how to map a `uid` to a folder. If you have the folder location stored in the database somewhere, do a query to find it and do a `header("Location: /the/folder");` header-redirect.

Answer (score 1):

what about this
1st if you dont provide null password

```
if($_SESSION['uid']=="")&&( $_SESSION['pwd']==""))
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');//redirect where ever you want
}
```

2nd if you provide even null password

```
if($_SESSION['uid']=="")&&( $_SESSION['pwd']!=""))
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');//redirect where ever you want
}
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: @frits Thanks gents, useful, and I do have the folder location/path in the DB.  Is mod_rewrite any use here?